# Can I use a 404 redirect in .htaccess to send bots to another domain?

Tags: .htaccess

Maybe this is a silly question but I want to check. if I have .htaccess file at example.com with the line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://someotherdomain.com
```

Would this be successful in redirecting mailicious bots that are looking for files to exploit at example.com? (I want to redirect them to someotherdomain.com) - assuming of course that the file does not exist.

ALSO, does this 404 redirect work on windows servers or just linux?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell me you own the other domain as well... Otherwise you could get in a lot of trouble for doing that. A better solution would be to just improve your server security to block them...

Comment: Absolutely the other domain would be mine. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I want to take mailicious bots away from other people sites and direct them to my site. Would my code work for that?

Comment: You don't really use htaccess to determine if requests are malicious or not. It could simply be a user that ran across a 404 error where the page was linked externally and has been removed.

Comment: I don't need to know if the user/bot is malicious, I just want to redirect them.

Comment: Then yes that's how you would do it. If you specify a full domain, Apache will redirect the user completely (the URL will change in the address bar). I do believe as long as you're still using Apache, it will work on either Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) for more details. it  works on both windows and linux servers!

Comment: as this is the only 'official' answer, I accept. Thanks for the useful link.